# How to get a class methods return type hint in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Are there other ways available for getting the return type of a class method?

What are the drawbacks of using `signature`?

One based on the docs, any others?:

> Note
>
> Some callables may not be introspectable in certain implementations of
> Python. For example, in CPython, some built-in functions defined in C
> provide no metadata about their arguments.

Example usage:

```
>>> import inspect

>>> class Test(object):
...     def some_method(self, data: int=1) -> int:
...             return data
... 

>>> inspect.signature(Test.some_method).return_annotation

<class 'int'>
```

reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature

Stems from an issue where I'm trying to determine how feasible it is to create multiple swagger return types on a django model @property field with a `Union[A, B]` return type.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200048/how-to-get-the-parameters-type-and-return-type-of-a-function

Comment: @Bill that's a great related question, thanks for linking it, and actually looks like it had an answer several years later for when `signature` was added to python 3.3.

Comment: One simple way is to just look at the `return` key of the function's `__annotations__` attribute.