# Parsing Function names, arguments, return value from python file?

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Im trying to get all the function names, with their arguments, and return's of a python file, using python script.

Tried to use AST library with FunctionDef class but couldn't able to extract the information I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked module `inspect` which is there is python stdlib?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/139198/10940584) recommends the `inspect` module for getting a list of functions; it can be used (but isn't required) for [accessing function parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051447/10940584). To the best of my knowledge, Python's design [doesn't really allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15200247/10940584) getting this information about a function's return values; so you might have to annotate those yourself, be it with a docstring, custom attribute, type hint, etc.